# Is it possible to assign running other py script on multiprocessing?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, spyder, python-multiprocessing

I was testing multiprocess function on python but I am not sure if it is possible.
Here is brief explanation on what I want to do

1. On mother.py (which is supposed to be a main) I defined few variables that will be handled in the designated function.
2. I have defined the function run_py.py, which is nothing but simple execfile, because I want to run the code in Spyder environment on windows.
3. In run_py the function will run an external python code(partest.py) that handles the variables defined in mother.py. In the code I have submitted below, it just writes down what kind of variables are handled to the function.

So basically, I run a function defined in other python file via run_py.py.
And there is no problem in running it in series, but it does not do a thing when I define it via multiprocessing.

In short, if I run the code with run_py(My), the partest.py will write log files as I want them to be. But the log files will not be created if I run it via multiprocess.

Is there anything I did not do right? Or is there anyway I can get the feed-back on Spyder interface?
EDIT: I'm using Spyder 5.4.2 and Python 3.8.2

Below is the code I wrote.

```
#mother.py
import os, sys
import multiprocessing
import logging
import time
import time,datetime
from run_py import run_py
from run_py import call_back

def main():
    
    pool= multiprocessing.Pool()
    
    Zv=[1,2,3,4]
    Yv=[1,2,3,4]
    Xv=[1,2,3,4]

    # Define MY
    My={};
    aaa='SCRIPTs\\partest.py'    
    My['SCRIPT']=aaa;    
    My['ZVEC']=Zv;
    My['YVEC']=Yv;
    My['XVEC']=Xv;
    My['LOGSPATH']='LOGs\\'
    
    for zvar in My['ZVEC']:
        if zvar: My['ZVAR'] = zvar
        for yvar in My['YVEC']:
            if yvar: My['YVAR'] = yvar
            for xvar in My['XVEC']:
                My['XVAR'] = xvar
                
                My['STUDYnum']='_'.join([str(My['ZVAR']),str(My['YVAR']),str(My['XVAR'])])
                print(My['STUDYnum'])
                # pool.apply_async(run_py, args = (My, ), callback = call_back)                
                run_py(My)
                time.sleep(0.5)
                print('Step Done')
    
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('Pool done')
    
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

```
#run_py.py
import sys

def run_py(My):
    #call py code to exec a single process run
    execfile(My['SCRIPT'],globals(),locals())
    sys.stdout.flush()
    return My['RETURN']

def call_back(result):    
    resulst.append(result)
```

```
#partest.py
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import time, datetime
import os , sys

studyi=My['STUDYnum']
logfile  = '%s%s.log'%(My['LOGSPATH'],studyi)

sys.stdout = open(logfile,'w') # redirect all prints to this log file

print ('****************************************************')
print ('   Scenario <%s>'%studyi)
print ('')
print ('   {:%Y-%b-%d   %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now()))
print ('****************************************************')
print ('')

sys.stdout.close()
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
My['RETURN'] = [studyi]
```